# Android - Fragment to Main Layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, fragment, navigation-drawer

Good afternoon,

I was following a tutorial to create a drawer menu for Android.
As programmed, came to me the need for when I go into a Fragment Class, wanted on the menu when you press on the Home, back to the Home (MainActivity) and not for another class.

I leave here my code of this project.

***MainActivity.java***

```
package pt.projects.bpn.menudrawerproject;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private NavigationView nvDrawer;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();
    mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

    nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
    setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
    return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,  R.string.drawer_close);
}

private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView nvDrawer) {
    nvDrawer.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
                    selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                    return true;
                }
            });
}

private void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass;
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_home_fragment:
            fragmentClass = null;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
            fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
            fragmentClass = SecondFragment.class;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_third_fragment:
            fragmentClass = ThirdFragment.class;
            break;
        default:
            fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
    }
    if(fragmentClass != null) {
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
    }
    else {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        for(int i = 0; i < fragmentManager.getFragments().size(); ++i) {
            fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    mDrawer.closeDrawers();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
}
```

Can you please clarify me how i can do that?

***EDIT***
I update the code for the tips from the comments bellow.
Now, the graphic layout take no changes.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what exactly you wanted to say, so clarifying, you want to go to home page when clicked on Home button right?

Comment: Exactly @himanshu1496
What I want at this point for the work is: when I click on a fragment (for example, First call me the layout for this fragment thereof), I create on my menu a button to return to the Home, ie for MainActivity

Comment: So you can simply `pop` all the `fragments` from `backstack` on clicking `home` button. I guess that will solve your problem right?

Comment: @himanshu1496 Well i will try it. But this function only will be trigger when user click on the item menu "Home".
The code will be the same right?

Comment: yes, bug where is your `home` menu button exactly? Just create a function which will pop all the fragments, and call it whenever `home` button is clicked.

Comment: @himanshu1496 i try what u said but for my case do not work.
Because the layout stay the same. Example: go to First fragment, then second fragment and then when i click on the Home option in Menu, the layout stays the same (in the example: the layout from Second Fragment stay's the same)